# my ubuntu was so lame

Tags: system-requirements

i want to ask why my ubuntu was working to slow for everything when i was inputing data and see my email inbox it was always loading , sometimes it was hangs , not responding 
with requirement core2duo , ram 512mb and HDD 80GB 
do you have any solution for this problem?
thank you before

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry but your computer is not powerful enough to run current Ubuntu well. In my experience you will need at least 1 Gb of RAM for smooth execution.

You can try a light weight Ubuntu remix like [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/), it should run fast enough in your setup, but it will lack some features and eyecandy.